# render_to_string seems to remove value of an variable

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, render-to-string

I am creating a like unlike button in Django and I ran into a wall. I am using ajax grab id and post to render to string. When button gets clicked first time everything is fine but render_to_string does not return value attr. And I have no idea why?

**def in views I have:**

```
def like_post(request):

# post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST['post_id'])
id = request.POST.get('id')

post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
# check if this user already  
is_liked = False
if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
    post.likes.remove(request.user)
    is_liked = False
else:
    post.likes.add(request.user)
    is_liked = True
context = {
    'is_liked': is_liked,
    'value': id,
}

if request.is_ajax():
    html = render_to_string('post/like_section.html', context, request=request)
    return JsonResponse({'form': html})
```

**section where this is being rendered:**

```
  <div id="like-section">
     {% include 'post/like_section.html' %}
  </div>
```

**my jquery**

```
 $(document).on('click', '#like', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr("value");
    var url = '{% url "like_post" %}';

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: {
            id: id,
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {

            $('#like-section').html(response['form'])

        },
        error: function(rs, e) {
            console.log(rs.responseText)
        }
    });

});
```

**section that is being rendered**

```
  <form action='{% url "like_post" %}' method="post">

    {% csrf_token %} {% if is_liked %}

     <button name="post_id" class="likes" id="like" type="submit" value="{{ Post.id }}" like-count="{{ Post.likes.count }}">click 1</button> {% else %}
     <button name="post_id" class="likes" id="like" type="submit" value="{{ Post.id }}" like-count="{{ Post.likes.count }}">click 2</button> {% endif %}

  </form>
```

**{{Post.id}} is not being rendered via render_to_string
result I get back is this:**

```
<form action='/like/' method="post">

    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="0isfVRqNKFrDpFjCBi8jdFUgYzaw13YsEdPZV0dwi3SyExUmfOKLZUgFxaDAWhQ1"> 
    <button name="post_id" class="likes" id="like" type="submit" value="" like-count="">click 2</button> 

</form>
```

Seems like the variable is not being picked up, if I hardcode in any number and not pulling from db as `{{ Post.id }}` all seems to be working fine. Any idea what I am missing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not pass `Post` to the context, so indeed the template engine can not render it. You should pass this, for example with:

```
def like_post(request):
    id = request.POST.get('id')
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    # check if this user already  
    is_liked = False
    if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        post.likes.remove(request.user)
        is_liked = False
    else:
        post.likes.add(request.user)
        is_liked = True
    context = {
        'is_liked': is_liked,
        'value': id,
        'Post': post  # ←  add post to the context
     }
    if request.is_ajax():
        html = render_to_string('post/like_section.html', context, request=request)
    return JsonResponse({'form': html})
```

Comment: even if I do that It looks like I get the same error. It passes the value but after render_to_string it doesn't work

Comment: @Dula: do you pass it as `Post` or as `post`, note that variables are case sensitive. so if you render it with `{{ Post.id }}`, you should pass it as `'Post' : post`

Comment: @Williem Van Onsem: I do it like this: context = {
  'is_liked': is_liked,
  'value': id,
  'Post': post
 } and my build is something like this :  post = get_object_or_404(PostJoke, id=id)

Comment: I got it. That's exactly what it was thank you very much. My variable name was wrong on context

Comment: @Williem Van Onsem: okay so my problem now is that if I click a like on any post on the lis (for loop) it will update all of them. I guess is my jquery target ...hm...

Comment: The `name=""` of the button is `post_id`, not `id`, so shouldnt this be `reuest.POST['post_id']` instead?

Comment: @Williem Van Onsem: Why would that make a difference? I need to request id correct? maybe I am just not understanding render_to_stirng

Comment: @Dula: but exactly where do you pass the `id` in the POST request? Your template does not show the form where you produce a request with the `id`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222841/discussion-between-dula-and-willem-van-onsem).